# Remove div from DOM with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I´m trying to remove the "closest" div with a class of: flak
I have tried using "parent" but it will remove a higher div.
I need to remove the div with a class of ".flak" and all it´s children.

**HTML**

```
<div class="well" id="flakDiv"> 
  <span id='deleteFlak' class='pull-right'>x</span>
  <div class="flak nopadding" id="77">
  <div class="flakSideUp nopadding"></div>
  <div class="flakMiddle">Flak <b><span>88<span></b><p>88</p></div>
  <div class="flakSideDown nopadding"></div>
</div><br>
```

**Js**

```
//Flak HTML setup
var flak = $('<div class="flak nopadding" id="'+flakId+'"><div class="flakSideUp nopadding"></div><div class="flakMiddle">Flak <b><span>'+flakNr+'</span></b><p>'+ chosenObjNr +'</p></div><div class="flakSideDown nopadding"></div></div><br>');

//Delete flak
$('#deleteFlak').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.flak').remove();
});
```

Comment: Please provide the actual HTML output, not the php script that generates it.

Comment: Can´t see why this should make a diference. But done!

Comment: can you fiddle the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$.fn.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/),as it looks from immediately following sibling. the `$.fn.closest()` method traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM tree including itself.

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

*Use*

```
//Delete flak
$('#deleteFlak').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.flak').remove();
});
```

Comment: Can you additionally tell me how to get that class .flak id= ? Like: var flakId = $(this).next('.flak');

Comment: @Mjukis, `$(this).next('.flak').attr('id')` read id attribute then use remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rogzab2u/).

Following code finds the class **flak** under the parent DIV of span **#deleteFlak**.

Javascript code :

```
$(function(){
    $('#deleteFlak').on('click', function(){
        alert('close');
        $(this).closest('div').find('.flak').remove();
    });
});
```

Hpe this helps.